# Custom Visualforce version of a Related List, including New button

Tags: visualforce

I would like to create my own version of a related list in Visualforce, however I would also like to include the create New record button. My object is Case and has record types, so unfortunately a link to https://eu5.salesforce.com/500/e doesn't work, and autopopulates the user's default record type.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this URL to get the user to record type selection screen

'/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Account&nooverride=1&save_new_url=%2F001%2Fe'

This one is for Account and you can change it to case (500 is prefix for case) by ent=Case.

If this needs to be used for any custom objects using ent=mycustomobject__c wont work.

To make it work for custom objects too you will have to use the 15 character id of that custom object. To find it, go to:

Setup
Create
Objects
Select your object and check the URL in your browser(for example: https://cs87.salesforce.com/01I8E0000008XjE?setupid=CustomObjects)

This is the id that we need(01I8E0000008XjE)

Then, just replace the ent=Account with ent=01I8E0000008XjE

Hope it helps.